# How can I install lstat in macOS?

Tags: xcode, macos, npm, macos-monterey

I have an application that is dependent on `node-gyp` package.

The error is: `YN0001: │ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/stefan/MyProject//node_modules/node-gyp'`

I was able to install it globally and it works fine. Although when I try to use my app this `node-gyp` package is dependent on another system command line called `lstat` which is not present in the latest macOS.
I am unable to find resolve this through npm, brew, or MacPorts. Does anybody know how can I add `lstat` into my macOS?

My system is: MacbookPro 16-inch 2021, apple M1 chip, running on macOS Monterey (12.2.1), XCode 13.3, python 3.8, npm 8.3.1, node v16.14.0

Answer (score 2):

I have a workaround which works for me. I just created a symbolic link called `lstat` to `/usr/bin/stat`. Then I could create my react application. Something like:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/stat /usr/bin/lstat
```